# Cerrar e ir a un activity tras x tiempo de inactividad del usuario

Tags: android

Deseo realizar un método (service, alarm , etc) que pueda calcular  después de x tiempo de inactividad del usuario con el app

, que cierre la activity actual

y te mande a la activity inicial (iniciar sesión)

Muchas gracias

Comment: inactividad es que este abierta sin tocar nada o que pueda mandarse a background tambíén, para en base a esto responder...

Comment: que pueda usarse desde background , mi problema mas puntual es como reconocer que el usuario no esta usando la app ..--  Gracias. por interesarse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase CountDownTimer, acá te dejo un ejemplo de como usarlo

```
private long startTime=15*60*1000; // 15 MINS IDLE TIME
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){

    super.onUserInteraction();

    //Reset the timer on user interaction...
    countDownTimer.cancel();            
    countDownTimer.start();
}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
        // CIERRA LA APP MATANDO EL PROCESO Y VUELVE A ABRIRLO. 
         android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
}
```

En el método onFinish tendrías que ejecutar la acción de iniciar otra actividad.

Comment: ok. todo correcto. pero como identifico el tiempo del usuario y su inactividad con el app.? osea. como se cuando el usuario usa o no el app? .. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Cuando el usuario no está usando la app?, aplica que esté dentro de la app pero sin hacer algún click a algo?

Comment: que pueda usarse desde background , mi problema mas puntual es como reconocer que el usuario no esta usando la app. sin hacer algun clic en el app ..-- Gracias. por interesarse

Comment: Actualicé la respuestá implementando el CountDownTimer, posiblemente te sea de ayuda con el método de onUserInteraction ya que el timer sigue corriendo cuando la aplicación está en background, sólo tendrías que ejecutar tu acción en el método onFinish.

Comment: muchas gracias.. voy a probarlo.. al parecer es lo que necesito.. espero que super.onUserInteraction();  me ayude a detectar la inactividad.. gracias..

Comment: Excelente, si lo resolviste con éxito, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada :)

Comment: Hola .. y muchas gracias.. me ayudaste un montón. aun que aun tengo algunas dudas de cosas extras. pero voy a investigar. pero por el momento .tu respuesta me ayudo. Muchas gracias. ah. editare. mi publicación . para los que tengan la misma duda.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ,  me ah sido de utilidad

Answer (score 0):

Una vez tienes el tiempo, en nanosegundos, lo almacenas en tiempo y ejecutas el siguiente código, el Handler es por así decirlo, el manejador de hilos concurrentes que enviará un mensaje a la APP (mainThread) para ser ejecutado su código escrito en el método run().

```
int tiempo = 0; // Indícalo.
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Intent i = new Intent(ActividadActual.this, ActividadPrincipal.class);
        ActividadActual.this.startActivity(i);
        ActividadActual.this.finish();
     }
}, tiempo);
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias. como lo usaría ?

Comment: la idea es poder detectar el tiempo de inactividad del usuario , osea si el usuario vuelve a usar la app este tiempo se resetea y vuelve a iniciar. ademas como usuaria este código para cual quier activity de mi proyecto  Muchas gracias